# How to properly use /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -F

Tags: grep, solaris

I have a problem producing filtering out hanzoMollusc (2)from my grep.

```
https://node.hanzo.com/production/application/ (1) 

https://node.hanzoMollusc.com/Messaging/Receiver (2)
```

My grep command is this for (2) which is working just fine.

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E 'node.hanzoMollusc.*Exception' diag* | grep -c 2013-03-28
```

Problem is if I wanted to search for (1) I need to modify the grep command a bit and use -F where its stated in the manual

```
"Matches using fixed strings. Treats  each pattern  specified as a string instead of a regular expression"
```

This is what I have come up so far... which is not working....

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -F 'https://node.hanzo.com/application/*Exception' diag* | grep -c 2013-03-28
```

My problem lies in the domain part which is node.hanzo and node.hanzoMollusc that is why I didn't use -E on (1). Can anyone help me to fix this.

## Edit

I was able to get what I want exactly with a few tweaks from Gilles example. Actually he was right I tried reading my question and it wasn't clear. My problem boils is this.

I have a problem filtering this

```
https://node.hanzoMollusc.com/Messaging/Receiver
```

everytime I use this command:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E 'node.hanzoMollusc.*Exception' diag* | grep 2013-03-28
```

because it also shows up both node.hanzo and node.hanzoMollusc on the results.

I tweaked Gilles example and I was able to get the result right

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E '(https://node.hanzo.com/production/application)[/ ].*Exception' diag*
```

Thanks alot Gilles.

Comment: Have you an example output you want to filter ?

Comment: grep -F will look for an actual asterisk character where you have a "*" in the search string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to match: your examples are contradictory.

`grep -F` matches an exact string. If you put a `*` in the argument, it only matches a `*` character in the file.

If you want to allow matching several strings, use `-E` and the `|` operator. For example, the following command matches lines containing `https://node.hanzo.com/production/application/somepath Exception Foo` or `https://node.hanzoMollusc.com/Messaging/Receiver/somepath Exception Foo` (where the `/somepath` part is variable and can be omitted).

```
grep -E '(https://node.hanzo.com/production/application|node.hanzoMollusc.com/Messaging/Receiver)[/ ].*Exception' diag*
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, thanks alot for your help!